# Delete date and time from text file

Tags: perl

I have a text file having date and time in below mentioned format at the 4th line of the file:

```
[0x1FFD]     LOG                 2017/02/22 06:20:48.644  Diagnostic Version                                Length: 0149                                                255
```

Now, I have to delete the string "**2017/02/22 06:20:48.644**"in the file.

This date and time is not constant and will change whenever I save the file(it takes the current date and time).

As I am not a perl coder , I am finding it difficult to figure out the way.

**NOTE**: I need to make changes in input file only. I don't need to create a seperate output file.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could probably read the file and then use Regex on it to search and replace the timestamp in it.

Comment: Could you please suggest the regex to fetch the time and date

Comment: If the format is _always_ the same, here is the simple version: `$line =~ s|\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{3}||;`.  You go through lines (`while (<$fh>)`), have the above regex and then write the line out to a new file. If there is no match (no date on a line) then nothing happens in the regex and that line is written out unchanged, ie. copied.  After you've processed the file you overwrite the original (use `move` from `File::Copy`). You cannot "edit" the original, you have to write out a new file and then copy it over the original.

Comment: But please note that SO isn't really for questions like this one. Here people post specific problems with their code and get help on how to fix it. If you try it yourself and show us what you did you'll get far better responses than my comment above. (Which does tell you exactly how to do it -- so maybe try?)

Comment: If the `LOG` and `Diagnostic Version` is the default keyword or else its alpha character then wont worry about the regex just do it with `s/(LOG\s)(.*?)(\sDiagnostic Version)/$1$3/gi;`

Comment: @zdim: The code worked fine with your regex.
Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $str = " [0x1FFD]     LOG         2017/02/22 06:20:48.644  Diagnostic Version     and more stuff";
$str =~ s|\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{3}||;
print $str;
```

if it is in a file you need to loop through the file and print each line to exclude the date.

Like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;
open FILE, "<", "filename.log" or die $!;
my @list = <FILE>;
foreach my $str(@list) {
     $str =~ s|\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{3}||;
     print $str;
}
close(FILE);
```

So from there you can figure out how to write it back to the original file. :)

Comment: The second `s///` will replace any two spaces with one on all lines that have two spaces -- even those which weren't matched by the first `s///`. Comments. Using `open my $fh, ...` is just better than `FILE` or such. Any literal spaces in a regex are hard to read, and two next to each other doubly so. Perhaps escape them, or use `\x20`, or `\N{SPACE}`, or `[ ]` (character class :)

Comment: @zdim, yes, the only reason why  I do `s/  / /g` was to show the results by eliminating some spaces from the string. Thanks for the other suggestions, will change the code and test :)

Comment: One more comment. Since the file is read in list context, `close(FILE)` belongs right after that, _before_ the loop.  This may matter since in this way OP would redirect the output to overwrite the same file. So better close it before we start printing. (Prints to terminal may be line-buffered, so they go right as they happen. Shell's redirection _is_ buffered but it may open-and-truncate right away.)  // Another way would be to open an output file, read line-by-line and print to it, and after the loop `move` it onto the original (after filehandles are closed).

Answer (score 0):

> You can use the `Tie::File` module to update the input file at single call.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Tie::File;

my $str = 'data1.txt';

tie my @lines, 'Tie::File', $str or die $!;

my $joinLines = join "\n", @lines;
```

> Either use #1 or #2 for based on the regex modification

```
#1. $joinLines=~s/(LOG\s)(.*?)(\sDiagnostic Version)/$1$3/g;
#2. $joinLines =~ s/\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{3}//;


print $joinLines;

@lines = split /\n/, $joinLines;

untie @lines;
```

> Please check and test at your end.